# Calculate values in logarithmic scale

Tags: python, scale, logarithm, natural-logarithm

I want to redraw this `Body Weight` scale in bitmap editor pixel by pixel. As I understood this is a logarithmic scale, but what is the logarithm - binary or decimal?

How to calculate distance between lines in pixels. Maybe it's better to count from 1 to 70 and than reverse it.

```
values = []
for kilos, value in enumerate(range(1, 71)):
    //  some logic
    values.append([kilos, pixels])
reverse(values)
```

[image]

Comment: Since the distance from 10 to 20 is the same as the distance from 20 to 40, I'm going to hazard a guess of Log 2.

Comment: Since log_n(a) = log(a) / log(n), the base doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want a height in pixels of 500, you can use this to get the intervals:

```
import math
pixels = 500
offset = math.log(10)
for x in range(10, 71, 10):
    print x, int(pixels * (math.log(x) - offset) / (math.log(70) - offset))
```

This is the output:

```
10 0
20 178
30 282
40 356
50 413
60 460
70 500
```

The pixel counts are just the differences between the start and end of each interval. Change 500 to fit your application.